# Prestashop 1.7 redirect to admin dashboard problem

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have issue with filltering in admin/catalog/products when i want reset saved filters I am redirect to main admin dashboard.

I tried remove cache and sessions but problem is still same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue here :(

I created a different superadmin user, and it works fine... Something wrong with the first user, but I can't find where...

Edit :

Just solved my problem as folows :

- went into DB, table ps_admin_filter
- found the filter that caused issue
- deleted the record
- everything is back to normal...

I would be interested in how and why this happen if anyone knows...